# What effect does termination impedance have on propagation speed?

Tags: impedance, oscilloscope, signal-processing, cables

I fed a 1 MHz sinewave from a 50 ohm signal generator source into a 100 ft long RG58C coax cable "T"ed into a 100 MHz dual trace scope channel 1. The other end of the cable was fed into channel 2 of the scope and I expected to see about a 150 nano second delay. Instead, I had 970 nano seconds between the top crest of the two channels. The input impedance of the scope is 1 meg. Putting a 50 ohm termination at channel 2 gave me the 150 ns delay, but why was the unterminated input at channel 2 not 150 ns???

Comment: This will be best understood if you simulate it. Many reflected sine version overlap to cause a resulting wave. The sum of sine waves of same f, is again a sine at f with more phase shift. Also what do you mean by 970 ns ? That is the same as -30 ns right ?

Comment: Please produce a diagram of your set up and not that 1 mHz = 0.000001 Hz.

Comment: It's 0.001 Hz tho

Comment: Based on what Tobalt said, it might not be a delay that you're seeing (the propagation is at least half the speed of light), but a phase shift. It's very hard to measure delay - probably more than most scopes can do. There's a steady state phase shift through a coaxial, which in theory is zero when there's a perfect match. A mismatch (like Tobalt said) leads to reflections and back and forth travel, which after a tiny bit of time comes to a steady state with some phase shift and also lower amplitude (in case of a mismatch). Try the Falstad simulator - it has a T.line component.

Comment: LTSpice also has a transmission line component, but on Mac it doesn't seem work out of the box? Some config needs to be done? Anyhow, Falstad's works easily.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Tobalt said, it might not be a delay that you're seeing (the propagation is at least half the speed of light), but a phase shift. There's a steady state phase shift through a coaxial, which in theory is zero when there's a perfect match. A mismatch leads to reflections and back and forth travel, which after a tiny bit of time comes to a steady state with some phase shift and also lower amplitude (in case of a mismatch). Try the Falstad simulator - it has a T.line component.

On the other hand, even when the loads are matched (coax is the same as resistor load), there's indeed a delay that look like phase shift. And numbers like 100 ns make sense for a 100 ft cable.

But when there's an impedance mismatch, it seems delay might not be the best way to describe it, because there's such a jumble of waves travelling back and forth in the coax (which at the ends of the coax "resolve" to "ordinary" current and voltage). They usually talk of voltage loss and phase shift after the system adjusts to steady state - the jumble of waves in the coax very quickly finds a steady state, and becomes a standing wave at every point inside the coaxial, and at the edges (at the edges the wave world model ends and then we think about it as ordinary current & voltage once more - i.e. same voltage at every point on a short circuit).

So the 900 ns is not extra delay - the travel speed along the cable is the same regardless of the load, but the phase shift at steady state.

(A standing wave inside the coaxial is not a DC voltage throughout, but rather, that the back and forth motions of the constituent sinusoidal waves are no longer visible as horizontal motion, but appear as vertical motion - like a vibrating guitar string (but a vibrating string in a guitar, but not exactly the same, because string of a guitar will show a standing wave only if the period times speed of propagation is equal to the length of the guitar string or integer multiples thereof, whereas a coxial will develop a standing wave at any frequency). Thus in a 100 ft coaial quite a number of 1 mhz sinusodial periods will be appearing to move vertically up & down around zero volts). The voltage your scope sees is the voltage at the border of the standing wave - there the wave model ends, and you can treat that voltage as ordinary voltage being applied to the load resistor.

Also, perhaps a higher frequency than 1 mhz will increase the transmission line effect, but at 1 mhz it's borderline even for a 100 ft cable..

In my view this is interesting stuff, that's rarely explained in books. Some people think that to simulate a transmission line you need to simulate lots of passive components. But more fundamentally a lossless TL can be simulated moment by moment by the wave model as long as the waves are collapsed at the edges to "commonplace" voltages.